# puppet use hiera with module

Tags: linux, bind, puppet

I am going to use puppet bind module from

https://github.com/thias/puppet-bind

any idea how I can use hiera in yaml format with this?

I have tried using this in Hiera, but it does not pass the values to the module.

```
---
classes:
  - 'bind::server'

profile::bind::conf:
    '/etc/named.conf':
        zones:
            'example.com': ['type master', 'file ]
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters cannot be bound to the module's classes automatically - zones are created through a `define`.

Creating values for `define` instances in Hiera is a two-step process.

1. Create the data. Your's is fine, but the key is misleading.

e.g.

```
bind_server_confs:
  '/etc/named.conf':
    zones:
      'example.com': ['type master', 'file ]
```

2. Create resources from the hash using the `create_resources` function.

like

```
create_resources('bind::server::conf', hiera('bind_server_confs'), {})
```

The default result of `{}` will (correctly) lead to no resources being created.